# Problem with getting pixel information using SetMouseCallback, c++, OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I've been trying to get information about pixels that I click on. I've been using function SetMouceCallback and honestly I don't know exactly how it works.

```
void startGUI()
{
    VideoCapture video;
    Mat frame1;
    video.open("/Users/Dominik/Desktop/Legia22.mov");
    video.read(frame1);

    Mat img = frame1.clone();

    namedWindow("My Window", 1);
    setMouseCallback("My Window", onMouse, &img);
    imshow("My Window", img);
    //********* I want to use leftClicks[] here 
    waitKey(0); 
}


static void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int, void* param)  
{

    Mat &img = *((Mat*)param); 
    static int counter=0;
    Point leftClicks[4];

     if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && counter<4)
     {
         Vec3b val = img.at< Vec3b >(y,x);
         cout << "left button clicked pos -  (" << x << ", " << y << ")" <<"\t colour bgr: "<< val << endl;
         leftClicks[counter].x = x;
         leftClicks[counter].y = y;
         circle(img, Point(x,y), 4, SCALAR_BLUE, -1);
           imshow("My Window", img);
         counter++;
     }

}
```

The following code works fine. Window is shown and on the first frame I can draw 4 circles. The points are printed in the terminal.
So basically what I'm trying to do is to get the array leftClicks[4] out of the function for further processing in other functions, eg. where the ****** are. 
The problem is that the type of function onMouse has to be void and the arguments can't be changed.

I noticed that the function setMouseCallback has pretty specified what onMouse function has to be and no changes to the function onMouse could be made...

So how can I get the array leftClicks[] out of the function onMouse?

Comment: Where does `counter` come from? And what exactly is the question here?

Comment: the question is -  how to get the array leftClicks out of the function onMouse?

Comment: If you only use `counter` to count inside of `onMouse` I would suggest to declare it as `static int counter` inside of `onMouse` and not as a global variable

Comment: thank You for suggestion

Comment: As `void* param` you can pass whatever you want, just make a structure which stores your `cv::Mat` and `leftClicks[]` array. Then pass its pointer to `setMouseCallback`. That structure of course is allocated in `startGUI`. And this is what you want.

Comment: Thank You @rafix07, that was the thing I didn't understand in the  setMouseCallback function. Have a good day!